# Box plot using pandas plot function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

I have a data frame

```
Date    Col1
2010    41
2010    11
2010    88
2009    27
2009    41
2010    85
2009    54
2010    65
2009    99
2009    61
2009    67
2010    54
2009    0
2010    15
2010    92
2010    72
2009    36
```

I need to create 2 boxplots one for each year with respect to their values in the col1 column.

```
df=pd.read_csv(filename)
df.boxplot(column=['Col1'],by=['Date'])
```

Not sure if my approach is correct

Comment: Your approach looks good.

Comment: Also `sns.boxplot(data=df, x='Date', y='Col1')`.